# Calling GetDiskFreeSpaceExW api from WindowsPhone 8.1

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-phone-8.1, pinvoke

I am trying to call GetDiskFreeSpaceExW Win Api call in my Windows Phone 8.1 application, and I am always failing the certification.

This function is in the List of supported Win32 APIs :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662956(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_ListofsupportedWin32APIs

My call:

```
        [DllImport("api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
                                              out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable,
                                              out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
                                              out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
```

Erorr:

> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=GetDiskFreeSpaceEx. Module=api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll.
>   File=Glide.WindowsCommon.dll.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the certification failure report anything?

Comment: Yes, it is telling me that this function (GetDiskFreeSpaceEx) from api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll is depricated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[DllImport("api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
                                      out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable,
                                      out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
                                      out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
```

Because you did not specify a `CharSet` value, this is marshalled with `CharSet` of `CharSet.Ansi` by default. You should specify `CharSet.Unicode` like so:

```
[DllImport("api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, 
    SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(...);
```

It seems that the certification process also requires explicit statement of the entry point name:

```
[DllImport("api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, 
    Entry point = "GetDiskFreeSpaceExW", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(...);
```

Comment: I still need to change it's name to GetDiskFreeSpaceExW inorder to pass...

Comment: I'm a little surprised by that. Let's try to bottom this out. Can you leave the name as `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` and add `EntryPoint = "GetDiskFreeSpaceExW"` to the `DllImport` spec? To my mind that would be the cleanest way to crack this one.

Comment: @PavelDurov - You can also use the `EntryPoint` property on the `DllImportAttribute` to specify that you want a different function export name. Edit: It appears that David Heffernan beat me to it

Comment: Can you confirm that setting `EntryPoint` suffices? Then I can edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is very confusing, simply changing the function name from GetDiskFreeSpaceEx to GetDiskFreeSpaceExW worked (passed the certification) + CharSet = CharSet.Unicode as in @David Heffernan answer  :)

Comment: Not confusing at all. All Windows API functions that deal with strings come in either an `A`- and `W`- suffixed version, for ANSI (narrow) and wide (Unicode) strings, respectively. This is normally sorted out by macros defined in the header files, but not so when you are P/Invoking. Using the actual name of the function works, as does David's solution with the `CharSet` attribute.

Comment: It is confusin, I would expect it to called as GetDiskFreeSpaceExW if I set CharSet = CharSet.Unicode without renaming the actual function name.